# What is the path of wlan.ko on Samsung 9500 or other Samsung phone?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

To make the 3G and WiFi interface working together on Samsung 9500 via adb shell, I need to execute "insmod wlan.ko" manually first. For most Android phones, the "wlan.ko" is under the path /systemn/lib/modules. But there is no directory "modules" under the "/system/lib" on 9500. Does anyone know where can I find this "wlan.ko" on 9500?

Answer (score 1):

try finding it /system/bin/busybox find -name "wlan.ko"